# when reading float numbers from excel by apache poi in java, float numbers considered as type of 'CELL_TYPE_STRING'

Tags: java, floating-point, apache-poi, readfile

I need to read only numeric data from excel file in java. I read all data by this code successfully:

```
try
{
    FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(new File("book1.xlsx"));

    //Create Workbook instance holding reference to .xlsx file
    XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(file);

    //Get first/desired sheet from the workbook
    XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

    //Iterate through each rows one by one
    Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet.iterator();

    while (rowIterator.hasNext()) 
    {
        Row row = rowIterator.next();

        //For each row, iterate through all the columns
        Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();

        while (cellIterator.hasNext()) 
        {
            Cell cell = cellIterator.next();

            //Check the cell type and format accordingly
            switch (cell.getCellType()) 
            {
                case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
                    int value = new Double(cell.getNumericCellValue()).intValue();
                    System.out.print(value + " ");
                    break;
                case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
                    //do nothing
                    break;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }
    file.close();
} 
catch (Exception e) 
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

book1.xslx:

```
Cr1 Co1 Co2 Co3
Co1 1   1.3 5
Co2 3   1   7
Co3 1.5 1.7 1
```

But the code result is:

```
1 5 
3 1 7 
1
```

This means, it consider 1.3, 1.5 and 1.7 as string and so, not print them in result. can anyone help me?

Comment: A `1.3` will definitely be a string value if it is created with an `Excel` language version and/or locale where the dot `.` has not a meaning within a number. Means it is neither decimal delimiter nor thousands separator nor delimiter within a date.

Comment: @AxelRichter thanks for your comment. how can i solve this problem? Is the true solution to write a function to convert this string values to float numbers?

Comment: At first I would try to determine **why** this problem exists. Why does someone input `1.3` into an `Excel` version where in language and/or locale `1.3` is not meant as a number when it should be a number? Why this one does not input the number in correct form according to the language and/or locale? In other words: Where is the `book1.xslx` coming from?

Comment: @AxelRichter I have made this excel file. You're right. I entered dot "." key for type numbers and so, my code read them as string. I update my excel file and the problem solved. thanks.

Comment: May I ask which decimal delimiter was correct for your locale (persian?)? Is it comma or is `Windows` really using Momayyez in this locale? Only from curiosity.

Comment: I'm Persian and  I use the key "." On the right side of the keyboard and besides the key "0" for decimal point.